# SAS do-Loops and set statements

Tags: sas, do-loops

Why does this macro work? (it does) The loop is able to start, despite the fact that the `nrows` variable is defined in the `set` statement inside the loop. Does SAS read the set statement before starting the loop? Where can I find documentation on this issue (which statements inside loops, if any, are executed before the loop starts)?

```
%macro get_last_n_rows(n, existing, new);
data &new.;
do _i_ = 1 + nrows - &n. to nrows;
  set &existing. point = _i_ nobs = nrows;
  output;
end;
stop;  
run;
%mend get_last_n_rows;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your question is: yes, SAS reads the number of rows available prior to the loop executing.  In fact, SAS reads the number of rows available before the data step executes; it's determined at data step compile time.  See for example, [this paper](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi23/Begtutor/p50.pdf) and [this paper](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/061-30.pdf), among many others.

See specifically the [SAS documentation for SET](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000173782.htm#a000173778):

> At compilation time, SAS reads the descriptor portion of each data set and assigns the value of the NOBS= variable automatically. Thus, you can refer to the NOBS= variable before the SET statement. The variable is available in the DATA step but is not added to any output data set.

Note this has nothing to do with the `do` loop; this is true for the entire data step (which is itself one large loop, of course).

Comment: Also worth noting, this could be done more easily with `firstobs` rather than `point` given how trivial it is to determine the number of observations.  Much more efficient.